# Do I need to import System.web.UI, to access Session in C# class Library?

Tags: c#

I Need use Session in C# class Library. For that I need to import Using System.Web.UI. My partial code is

```
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web


    namespace sundss_framework
    {
        public class package
        {

           Session["Sesval"]="12121";
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx?ppud=4

Comment: And what is your exact need for `Session`? If you project is not a web project, and all you want is a dictionary of key/values, why not use a plain `Dictionary<string,object>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `System.Web.UI`, just `System.Web`. Then access the session like:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["Sesval"] = "12121";
```